# Create a complex loop

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out how to create a complex loop but I don't find any solutions.
I have 2 tables and each of which can seat arbitrary amount of people.
I would like to create a loop to get all possibilities where I can put the people!
Each person are represented by an ID for example for 5 peoples.
each of digits are the person's ID.
I need to know what are the possible ways to seat the people!

```
table1   table2

(nobody) 12345
1        2345
2        1345
3        1245
4        1235
5        1234
12       345
13       245
14       235
15       234
23       145
24       135
25       134
34       125
35       124
45       123
```

Comment: Start by being clear and show us a hand simulation of what your want

Comment: Do you mean to get all possible seatings? Are the tables round? How many seats do the tables have? Does order matter?

Comment: This looks like counting up without same digits.

Comment: what about a bit of recursion?

Comment: phantOm the seats are not a problem I just need to know the possible ways to seat the people!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compute all subsets (table 1) of a set (the number of people). Table 2 is then simply the complement of table 1.

Comment: It is very easy, hint, go the opposite.

Comment: Yes for the second table isn't a problem, the problem is the loop to find the people in the table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned people = 5;

    printf("There are %u lights.\n", people);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1u << people; i++) {
        for (unsigned p = 0; p < people; p++) {
            if (i >> p & 1u) {
                printf("%u", p + 1);
            }
        }
        fputs("\t|\t", stdout);
        for (unsigned p = 0; p < people; p++) {
            if (!(i >> p & 1u)) {
                printf("%u", p + 1);
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But it is possible to give an explanation ?